# What is the reliable way to get commit hash after commit-msg hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm writing a script which is going to both pre-process and post-process git commit. For pre-processing I'm going to use `commit-msg` hook to add some information to commit message, but for post-processing I need to know hash of that commit. Is there a way to acquire hash without saving a script state somewhere (e.g. in case of `post-commit` hook)?

Answer (score 1):

In the `post-commit` hook you can execute `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the sha1 hash of the new commit.

Comment: Thanks, I know that, I was wondering is that possible to do that without having two hooks, because in that case I would have to store script state somewhere and I can't be sure that this `post-commit` hook was called for the same commit as `commit-msg` hook earlier (commit might be rejected for some reason, git might crash, etc).

Comment: That will not work for a bare repo. HEAD is always on master I guess. Any other solution?